# Unable to redirect in a golang web app. It sticks to one page

Tags: go, web-applications

This is code snippet from a file called upload.go.
I tried a lot of ways to redirect to another pages. I want to redirect to another page when the statements in  POST are completed running.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if r.Method == "GET" {
        // GET
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("upload.gtpl")

        t.Execute(w, nil)

    } else if r.Method == "POST" {
        // Post
        file, handler, err := r.FormFile("uploadfile")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer file.Close()

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", handler.Header)
        f, err := os.OpenFile("./test/"+handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer f.Close()

        io.Copy(f, file)

        img, err := imgio.Open("./test/" + handler.Filename)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        inverted := effect.Invert(img)
        if err := imgio.Save("filename.png", inverted, imgio.PNGEncoder()); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", handler.Header)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "www.google.com", http.StatusMovedPermanently)

    } else {
        fmt.Println("Unknown HTTP " + r.Method + "  Method")
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", upload)
    http.HandleFunc("/hi", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi")
        http.Redirect(w, r, "www.google.com", http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil) // setting listening port
}
```

It stays on the upload page what ever I do. Can anyone help me debug this?

Comment: Looking at your code, my best guess is, that your `fmt.Fprintf` calls with the `http.ResponseWrite` trigger calls to its `Write()` function which implicitly calls `WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)`. As only one header can be written, `http.Redirect` is unable to write the redirect header, resulting in a response with a 200 status. Removing the `fmt.Fprintf` calls should resolve this.

Comment: @Leon Worked like a charm. Thanks. Any ideas, what should I use instead of `fmt.Fprintf` ?

Comment: Well, if you want to redirect, there is no point in writing content to the response, as it will not be displayed after the redirect has been followed. You can still use `fmt.Println` or `fmt.Printf` to write to the terminal like in any other application.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to redirect after posting a form, you need to set the status to `http.StatusSeeOther` (303)

For example:

```
http.Redirect(w, r, "/index", http.StatusSeeOther)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is writing to the `ResponseWriter` before trying to send a redirect.

Upon the first [write](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Write) to the `ResponseWriter`, the status code (200 OK) and headers are sent, if they haven't already been sent, and then the data you passed to the writer.

If you intend to send an HTTP redirect, you can't write any response body to the `ResponseWriter`. From reading your code, it doesn't make much sense why you are writing to it in the first place. They look like debugging print statements, which you probably ought to send to `os.Stderr` or a logger instead of the web page response body.